# How cast Entity Framework Date into SQL Server Date with no time part

Tags: entity-framework, casting

I have a date value like `'2012/01/01 12:36:55'` and I want to filter SQL Server `date` value from this like `'2012/01/01'`

I can `convert('2012/01/01 12:36:55', date, 102)` in SQL Server to get `'2012/01/01'` value.

The question is : how can I convert date `2012/01/01 12:36:55`' in EF LINQ query to get `'2012/01/01'` value when my source object still is Queryable ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Use **EntityFunctions** Class in **System.Data.Objects** namespace, and it works very well

```
public static class EntityFunctions
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738626.aspx